# How can I lock icons in place in the Windows 10 system tray?

Tags: windows

I'm running the Core Temp app with three icons in the system tray on Windows 10 Home (64 bit). I can easily drag them to where I want them, but they will not stay there on restart. I am running the same app with the same three icons on a different computer with Windows 10 Professional, and they stay precisely where I put them.

Does anyone know what the issue is and how to fix it?

Comment: Task Bar properties, unlock, move icons, then lock the task bar again.

Comment: I have the same issue sometimes, they just randomly decide to disappear from time to time, so +1. Are you using Ditto by any chance? Asking because that has a bugged tray icon and not sure if it might be related to causing this problem. Also, you have latest Windows 10 I assume?

Comment: John, I've tried that a few times, even restarting in-between unlocks and locks. It doesn't seem to do anything for the issue.

Comment: Destroy666, I'm not using Ditto or any other modifications to the taskbar/tray. I get the regular updates, but I did lock the major update so that it would stop pestering me to switch to Windows 11. This problem has been going on for years before that though.